# Maven central version numbering

Tags: maven, maven-central

I'm trying to figure out if I've painted myself into a corner by using [screwy version numbers](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer%22%20AND%20a%3A%22owasp-java-html-sanitizer%22).

I published versions like:

- r136
- r156

while working out of an SVN repo.  After migrating the project to github I decided to use date-stamps and published

- 20150501.1

because I didn't take the time to understand the implication of version numbers.

I recently got my act together and read the [Maven Version Range Specification](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html)
and pushed

- 1.1

My understanding is that a dependency on

```
<version>[1.1,)</version>
```

will treat *20150501.1* as the latest release instead of the more recently released version *1.1*.

If I don't want to change artifact/group names and effectively orphan
code that depends on the old version, am I committed to date-stamp style
versions going forward?

Is there a standard way to deprecate artifacts?

This artifact is a piece of security infrastructure, so more users might use open ranges like `[20150501.1,)` for this artifact so that they pick up security-critical patches quickly.

Comment: Maybe you could consider changing the groupId/artifactId to completely avoid this issue. I am not sure about the consequences though. For example people will have to exclude the old dependency if they indirectly depend on it but want to use the new one.

Comment: @DidierL, Yeah.  I don't want to orphan code that depends on an old version.  Is there a standard way to deprecate an artifact in favor of one with a different id?

Answer (score 2):

Version ranges are evil because they make builds non reproducible. `[1.1,)` is an especially bad example because it matches both `1.1` and `2.0` which would very likely be source code incompatible with each other. `[1.1,2.0)` is better but may still break the build. Note that the last example would actually naturally solve your problem because it doesn't match `20150501.1`.

I would actually worry more about the effect on [`versions:use-latest-versions`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html), which is what sane people would use to update dependencies to the latest versions. With the version history of your project, that goal would always select `20150501.1` by default. Fortunately it turns out that the plugin supports an `excludes` directive that can be used to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `versions:*`.  I don't have control over the ranges that clients use / have used.  I just want reasonable ranges to work as their authors intended.